# Abuse of PHP function checkdnsrr

Tags: php

I have a php page which uses the PHP function `checkdnsrr` repeatedly.

Are their any limits on how many times I can use it in a day/hour/month etc before being banned?

Could my server IP be banned for using it too much?
Are their any other things that could happen if I use it too much?

Comment: That depends on the servers you wind up hitting. There isn't one single DNS server.

Comment: Banned by who or what from who or what? What name servers are you using? What is your agreement with whoever operates those name servers?

Comment: I have no idea about which servers it is checking, I'm just using checkdnsrr in my php code and was thinking if it is possible to even get banned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkdnsrr` queries your system's DNS resolver. If you have set up your own DNS resolver, you can query it as often as you want.

The preconfigured DNS resolver is usually located at your ISP (or data center provider in the case of hosting), or one of the big ones such as [Google](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) or [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/). Either way, these servers are typically high-performance and can easily handle thousands of requests per second. Unless you are calling `checkdnsrr` more than, say, ten times per HTTP request, your request volume will probably not stand out.

To find out what your DNS server is set to, read `/etc/resolv.conf` <sub>(On Windows, you have to execute `ipconfig /all`)</sub>. You can use the [`whois`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whois) command to find out who owns that DNS server, and contact them for further information.